# RecursiveTask<Integer> correct implementation

Tags: java, concurrency

Which one implementation is correct?

```
//previous code
leftSum.fork();
...
return (rightSum.compute() + leftSum().join());
```

or

```
return (leftSum.join() + rightSum().compute());
```

And say that it's incorrect, what are the result consequences?

Comment: both snippets would have a preceding [`leftSum.fork`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#fork--) call? you're just asking about the ordering for the addition?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is the correct one as you always need to follow the next order:

1. `fork()` to submit the left task to the pool in order to be executed in asynchronously.
2. `compute()` to execute the right task with the current thread
3. `join()` to make the current thread wait until it gets the result of the left (forked) task.

The second approach would make the thread wait before executing its task such that you lose the benefit of the parallel execution of your recursive tasks as they will be executed one after the other.

Comment: Thank you. If I choose the second option, a summ error   or an exception will be thrown (a 1Z0-804 question that  I have failed)?

Comment: the second approach does a serial execution of your tasks instead of a parallel execution as expected